# Firebase Database REST PUT overwriting data instead of adding

Tags: javascript, rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple Firebase Database, which looks like this:

> ```
> app-name
>  ᠁
> [-]⋯Users
>      ᠁
>      ᠁⋯⋯ Daniel: daniel@gmail.com
>      ᠁
>      ᠁⋯⋯ John: john@gmail.com
> ```

I want to make a REST PUT request, in order to add `Peter: peter@gmail.com` to the database, that should end looking like this:

> ```
> app-name
>  ᠁
> [-]⋯Users
>      ᠁
>      ᠁⋯⋯ Daniel: daniel@gmail.com
>      ᠁
>      ᠁⋯⋯ John: john@gmail.com
>      ᠁
>      ᠁⋯⋯ Peter: peter@gmail.com
> ```

I'm use the following javascript code:

```
httpPut: function(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('PUT', "https://app-name.firebaseio.com/Users.json", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    xhr.onload = function () {
        cc.log(this.responseText);
    };
    xhr.send("{\"Peter\": \"peter@gmail.com\"}");
},
```

The problem is that when I call `httpPut()`, it actually overwrites all Users content with only `Peter: peter@gmail`, leaving it like this:

> ```
> app-name
>  ᠁
> [-]⋯Users
>      ᠁
>      ᠁⋯⋯ Peter: peter@gmail.com
> ```

What can I do in order to only add a row instead of overwriting all Users content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:
Put request for writing  (sets data/rewrite)
Post request for adding  (like javascript array push)
Patch request for updating

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/#section-patch

If you make REST calls from a browser that does not support the preceding methods, you can override the request method by making a POST request and setting your method by using the X-HTTP-Method-Override request header

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/#section-method-override

Comment: what's the difference between writing and adding?

Comment: @Daniel rewrite all data